# Python's logging module misses "captureWarnings" function

Tags: python, logging, warnings

Python's standard logging module is [supposed to contain a useful captureWarnings function](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.captureWarnings) that allows integration between the logging and the [warnings](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html&ei=jXmITq-wJKqH0AXwlaQB&usg=AFQjCNH0PvEJIBmcbPD3i1zaVrwfN4ravQ) modules. However, it seems that my installation misses this function:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging.captureWarnings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'captureWarnings'
>>> import logging.captureWarnings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named captureWarnings
>>> import warnings
>>> import logging.captureWarnings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named captureWarnings
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such method in [Python 2.6.5's logging module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/library/logging.html). You need Python 2.7.

Comment: @JeffTsui You might try to backport it from https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1701 (and make a new answer if you get it working)